# Name for "get ready to run" mode

Tags: plc, twincat, codesys, st

This is a vocabulary question. I do now know where else to ask a question like that, because forums related to the English language are not filled with people who would be aware of what terms feel right to use in a plant.

I have a concept of a "get ready to run" mode in my project. This mode is not manual at all, it is just an automatic mode the intent of which is to get ready to switch to the main "run" mode.

I am looking for the right name for this mode. I am not a native English speaker, and I am not sure my current favorite, "stanbdy", is a good choice. This term is going to be used all over the place, both in code and in HMIs (including as a button label). Getting it right is important.  A short, meaningful and intuitive term is required.

Is "standby" a good choice, and are there other, better options?

Comment: "standby" and "idle" are often used for states where the state machine "is ready to start". If you want an intermediary between "idle" and "running", I use "starting".

Comment: To me, "idle" conveys the idea that the equipment is "doing nothing", whereas "standby" may have a bit more of an "active" connotation. In my "standby" modes, equipment might very well move or perform actions.  Something like "get and stay ready to run", although maybe more descriptive, would be too wordy, but I am trying to find a word that stays as close as possible to that meaning.

Comment: Is it GETTING READY to run (i.e. it takes time?).  INITIALIZING transitions to INITIALIZED???  READY is common, so is HOMING (if it's mechanical in nature), so HOMING transitions to READY?  or INITIALIZING to READY?  or just READY?

Comment: My mode is currently called "homing", and I think it is not the right choice, because there are cases where I use it where there is no actual motion yet there is still a concept of "getting ready".  Once "homing" is achieved, the homing mode stays active. It is not possible to transition to a "ready" state, because the system handles cases where something must be done that breaks the "homed" status while staying in homing mode (with the intent of eventually returning to the "homed" status). I hope that makes sense...

Answer (score 2):

Yes. From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/standby):

> **standby** *adjective*
>
> 1 : held near at hand and ready for use
>
> - a standby power plant
> - standby equipment

Also it is something everyone knows, so I wouldn't go with some other term. Not that I would know an alternative.

Comment: Thanks. Truth is, the plant I work for does not have English as its native language, but the system I am building is intended to be used elsewhere too. I do not have a good grasp of what "everyone knows". I have seen "standby" used to designate equipment that is offline but ready to replace another piece of equipment (e.g. that fails), so I wondered if "standby" used as the name of a mode of a (not failed) equipment was OK.  I seem to get from your answer that it would "feel" right to a native English speaker.

Comment: I think all the words that have been suggested here would be fine. However, as a native English speaker (in the USA), personally I think that the term "standby" suggests something that is prepared for use but not necessarily 100% ready, i.e. it would require some kind of changeover. On my projects I have used the terms "machine idle" and "machine ready" to indicate that the system is just a button push away from starting. Of course, English speakers from other regions might associate other meanings to these terms.

Comment: Thanks @kolyur. Your comment shows why this choice of wording is not so obvious, at least to me. When in "standby mode" (or whatever it ends up being called), the machine is not necessarily ready yet.  It is either ready (in which case it is idle), or trying to get ready (in which case it may not be). I do have a separate and necessary concept of a machine being "idle", which it can be even in "run" mode when not busy at the moment, for instance while waiting for another machine to feed it with a part.  "Ready" is a state, while my "standby mode" is a process trying to achieve that state.

Comment: I might add that it seems to me that "standby", as used in the expression "on standby", seems closer to my intended meaning.  A "standby computer" and a "computer in standby mode / on standby" seem to mean different things to me.  So maybe "standby" is not so bad after all for my purpose, since it designates a "machine in standby mode" rather than a "standby machine"?

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the PackML guidelines for standard names for various machine states: [PackML State Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Packml_highres.png)

PackML would use either 'Idle' or 'Starting' in your case I think.

Comment: Thanks. Of the two, "idle" is closer to the intended meaning, but for reasons explained above, I already use this word in the "not doing anything" sense. What I call a "mode" here is a global collection of behaviors (not a specific static state) that are associated with an intent.  A mode is not a state in a state machine.  In my "standby" mode, a machine may very well be doing something, but that something is about becoming, or staying, ready to run.

Comment: My modes are user-centric, and represent what the machine is being asked to do, whether or not it has been achieved. So an "off" mode would be intended to turn off the machine if/when possible. While in "off" mode, if the machine needs, say, to continue rotating a fan until some temperature drops under a threshold, the machine will stay on an keep the fan running. Then when the state of the machine (e.g. temperature) is OK to stop the fan, the fan will stop. So, to me being in "off" mode is distinct from being turned off, and similarly being in "standby" mode is distinct from being ready.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I still think your 'modes' can be represented by the PackML states. So your 'Off' mode is when a shutdown is requested. You could switch to the 'Completing' state, or the 'Stopping' state. When the temperature dropped enough you could then switch to 'Stopped'. Good luck!

Comment: There is no way I am exposing users to a state machine with 12 states. Furthermore, there are things that do not fit in there. For instance, I have setup modes and manual modes, that carry specific intents. On the same machine, I may have many run modes (ex: a normal "run" mode and a "test" mode that behaves slightly differently).

Comment: State machines rely on implicit path-dependent state embedded in the diagram. My code, while it may seem like it "lacks a proper model" or is "missing boxes", does away with the need of a state machine, because it constantly figures out what needs to be done next based on the whole state. Instead of assuming it can transition to a new state because it is in another state, it checks the entire state (positions, temperature, levels, etc.) and acts based on it. To me "Modes" are not sequences of transitions, they are sets of rules to decide "what do I do now".